# Python Selenium unexpected search outside the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

When I try to find elements inside the current element, the search occurs in the whole web page

For example I get some element:

```
year_block = browser.find_element_by_xpath('some condition')
```

There are several similar elements of such kind but I make sure that I've got the proper element using:

```
print(year_block.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

And then I need to find list of elements inside "year_block"
I use:

```
plant_id_block_list = year_block.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Plant number')]/following-sibling::input")
```

But in result I get the list of all such elements on a page instead of such elements only inside `year_block`

Where is the problem?

Comment: What's the html code in year_block and what are the contents of plant_id_block_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to find the elements with respect to `year_block` within the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) instead of using **//** you need to use **`.//`** which will initiate the search with respect to the context of `year_block`. Effectively your line of code will be:

```
plant_id_block_list = year_block.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Plant number')]/following-sibling::input")
```